# Does IOS PDFKit has OCR capabilities?

Tags: ocr, ios12, pdfkit, swift5

I know that PDFKit can extract text from PDF's with Images. But does it also supports PDF with Images (Images has text) to extract the text?

Comment: No, there is no magic built in OCR.